# Gunicorn backed Flask app not spawning a background thread

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I am new to Python and writing a Flask app that will run 2 servers (on different ports). Each server will keep adding the number received on each request. Once each server has received `NUM_CLIENTS_TO_SUM` requests, they need to send their sum so far to the other server where the final sum will be calculated "so far" (sum_from_other_server + sum_from_self). I configured Gunicorn to back my Flask app and started it with 1 worker and:
a. Multiple threads -- one of the servers always gets stuck in the `while` loop in `do_sum` function.
b. One thread - same

So, I decided to use the database where the intent is to run the query every configurable number of seconds. However, this `poll_db` function should be run as part of the background thread. I tried `flask_apscheduler` but somehow it never loads the function object (`LookupError: Error resolving reference server:poll_thread: error looking up object`). I also tried `threading` but the thread is never spawned. What is the best way to resolve this kind of a situation?

`server.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request
from config import Config
import requests, json
from multiprocessing import Value
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
import time
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

thread = threading.Thread(target=app.poll_db)
thread.start()

num_requests = Value('i', 0)
sum = 0

@app.route('/do_process', methods = ['POST'])
def do_process():
    client_data = request.get_json()
    
    dbconfig = {
                    'host': 'localhost',
                    'port': 3306,
                    'user': 'root',
                    'password': 'CAdemo@123',
                    'database': 'eta'
                }
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = """INSERT INTO eta_calc (secret_number, server_id, ts) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
   
    cursor.execute(sql, (client_data['secret_number'], 'SERVER1', datetime.now()))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    print('Secret number received: ' + str(client_data['secret_number']))

    with num_requests.get_lock():
        num_requests.value += 1
        global sum
        sum += int(client_data['secret_number'])
    
    print('NUM_CLIENTS_TO_SUM: ' + app.config['NUM_CLIENTS_TO_SUM'] + '::PEER_SERVER_URL: ' + app.config['PEER_SERVER_URL'] + '::num_requests.value: ' + str(num_requests.value) + '::sum: ' + str(sum))

    if num_requests.value == int(app.config['NUM_CLIENTS_TO_SUM']):
        send_sum_to_peer(sum, app.config['PEER_SERVER_URL'])
        with num_requests.get_lock():
            num_requests.value = 0
    
    return {'message': 'do_process success'}


def send_sum_to_peer(sum, url):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    return requests.post(url=url + '/do_sum', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(sum))


@app.route('/do_sum', methods = ['POST'])
def do_sum():
    data = request.get_json()

    print('data: ' + str(data))
   
    # while num_requests.value != int(app.config['NUM_CLIENTS_TO_SUM']):
    #     pass

    global sum
    final_sum = sum + data

    print('Final sum: ' + str(final_sum))
    
    return {'message': 'do_sum success'}


def poll_db():
    dbconfig = {
                    'host': 'localhost',
                    'port': 3306,
                    'user': 'root',
                    'password': 'CAdemo@123',
                    'database': 'eta'
                }
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    
    sql = """SELECT * FROM eta_calc"""
    
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in res:
        print(row)
    
    time.sleep(2)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=False)
```

`wsgi.py`

```
from server import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

`config.py`

```
import os 
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

class Config:
    # Default settings
    #FLASK_ENV = 'development'
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False

    # Settings applicable to all environments
    PEER_SERVER_URL = os.getenv('PEER_SERVER_URL')
    NUM_CLIENTS_TO_SUM = os.getenv('NUM_CLIENTS_TO_SUM')
    FILE_DB_DIR = os.getenv('FILE_DB_DIR')
    FILE_DB_NAME = os.getenv('FILE_DB_NAME')
```

`export PEER_SERVER_URL='http://localhost:8082'; gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8081  --threads 1 wsgi:app`
`export PEER_SERVER_URL='http://localhost:8081'; gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8082  --threads 1 wsgi:app`

`curl --location 'http://localhost:8081/process' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"secret_number": 1}'`

`curl --location 'http://localhost:8082/process' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"secret_number": 5}'`